# PDF in IFrame doesn't work in Chrome and Safari

Tags: php, pdf, iframe, webkit

I'm using a HTML-form which target is an iframe. In this frame a PDF is generated (using TCPDF) out of the given data and should be displayed within the iframe. The problem is, that in webkit browsers like Chrome or Safari with built-in PDF viewers the PDF isn't displayed. Instead, a very dark gray background is displayed - at least sometimes. In some cases which I could not figure out it works. When I use Firefox with Acrobat it works, too. So the PDF can't corrupt.
Unfortunately, I can't deliver an example for my problem, but did anybody have those problems, too, and can help me?

Thx.

Comment: Couldn't a PDF be both corrupt and yet work in Firefox and Acrobat?  If you configure the site to return to the iframe a static PDF that is know to otherwise work in webkit what result do you get? Also, if you download the PDF from Firefox and try to load it in Safari (sans iframe) what result do you get?

Comment: The intermittent failure makes me wonder if it is related to byte-range serving.  Can you turn that off on your webserver?

Comment: I recommend against trying to make PDFs load within frames.  While it may be possible to do this with some setups (OS+browser+plugin combinations), it certainly isn't universally compatible.  I use Chromium, Firefox and Epiphany, and have neither a built-in PDF viewer nor an Acrobat Viewer plugin for my operating system.  Give me a PDF download link any day.

Comment: Thanks. I just took a pdf which didn't work in Chrome but in Firefox, saved it and put it on the server. Then I replaced the "$pdf->Output(...)" call with "header('Location: pdf.pdf')" and it works! Any ideas? Before I use those commands, I clear the output with ob_end_clean() (while the first line of my script is ob_start()) and I stop with "exit", so that there shouldn't be any other output. Maybe some encoding stuff? What to you mean with byte-range servering, AllInOne?